# Genitivregierende Präpositionen + Nomen ohne Bestimmungswort

Tags: preposition, dative, genitive

Werden genitivregierende Präpositionen auch dann mit Genitiv benutzt, wenn das darauffolgende Nomen von keinem Bestimmungswort (z.B. Artikeln, Adjektiven) eingeleitet wird? Oder wird in diesen Fällen der Genitiv durch den Dativ ersetzt? z.B.:

> Ich möchte mittels Austausches mit Muttersprachlern meine Deutschkenntnisse vertiefen vs. Ich möchte mittels Austausch (Dativ) mit Muttersprachlern meine Deutschkenntnisse vertiefen.

oder

> Anstatt Biers trinke ich heute lieber Saft vs. Anstatt Bier (Dativ) trinke ich heute lieber Saft.

Comment: Beide Beispielsätze sind falsch.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ O je, kann ich sie irgendwie korrigieren?

Comment: _"Ich möchte mitte**l**s Austausch mit Muttersprachlern meine Deutschkenntnisse vertiefen"_ _"Anstatt Bier trinke ich heute lieber Saft"_ Sind die korrekten Sätze.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Vielen Dank!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Mach doch eine Antwort mit Begründung daraus!

Comment: @David Das ist manchmal schwieriger als man denkt ;-). Zu wissen das etwas falsch ist, bedeutet nicht unbedingt dass man alle Hintergründe korrekt erklären kann.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Wann steht bei Präpositionen, die eigentlich den Genitiv fordern, kein Genitiv?**

1. Im Plural, wenn man den Genitiv nicht erkennen würde, steht stattdessen der Dativ oder eine Konstruktion mit *von*:

   > Ausschließlich Getränken

   vs

   > ausschließlich der Getränke

   oder sogar

   > ausschließlich von Getränken

   (Durch den Artikel im zweiten Beispiel wird der Genitiv erkennbar, damit steht er auch da)
2. Wenn das Nomen, das im Genitiv stehen sollte, von keinem Artikel oder Adjektiv begleitet wird, nimmt man nicht etwa den Dativ, sondern *lässt das Substantiv unflektiert*

   > Dose mittels Dosenöffner öffnen
   >
   > Dose mittels eines Dosenöffners öffnen
   >
   > <s>Dose mittels einem Dosenöffner öffnen</s>

   (dein Beispiel mit "mittels", das ist eigentlich eine Überlappung mit (1))
3. Hat das Substantiv, das im Genitiv stehen soll, ein Attribut, das auch im Genitiv steht (z.B. einen Besitzer), dann steht das Substantiv im Dativ:

   > mittels Mutters großem Dosenöffner

*Anstatt* hat noch eine weitere Besonderheit, da es auch als *Konjunktion* benutzt werden kann - Dann hängt der Fall, den begleitende Substantive haben, überhaupt nicht von "anstatt" ab:

> Er liebte seine Mutter anstatt seinen Vater

(vgl. *Er liebte seine Mutter und seinen Vater*, Akkusativ)

> Er spielte mit dem Computer, anstatt Hausaufgaben zu machen

(dein Beispiel mit "anstatt")

Siehe auch [hier](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Praeposition/Kasus/Genitiv.html#Anchor-Genitiv-3800)

Allerdings hat sich bei vielen Sprechern in der Umgangssprache (und im Dialekt) der Dativ schon so festgesetzt, dass er allgemein schon fast akzeptiert wird.

Comment: Noch eine letzte Frage, bitte, was den "sondern lässt das Substantiv unflektiert" betrifft: Auch wenn das Nomen unflektiert sein mag, muss es in einem bestimmten Kasus sein, oder? Oder sind diese beiden Einordnungen eher selbstwidersprüchlich? Ich hatte halt noch nie ein Nomen gesehen, das in keinem Kasus wäre...

Comment: "unflektiert" meint die Nominalform, damit die Version, die du im Wörterbuch findest - Nominativ Singular.

Answer (score -1):

> "Ich möchte mittels Austausch mit Muttersprachlern meine Deutschkenntnisse vertiefen" "Anstatt Bier trinke ich heute lieber Saft" Sind die korrekten Sätze. – πάντα ῥεῖ

Sowohl *mittels* als auch *anstatt* leiten generell den Dativ ein. Mir fällt kein Satz ein, bei dem auf diese Wörter der Genitiv folgt (außer Konstrukte wie "anstatt des Vaters Weisungen zu folgen, [...]", hierbei bezieht sich jedoch das "des Vaters" auf die Weisungen, welche im Dativ stehen.)

Comment: Sowohl *mittels* als auch *anstatt* fordern traditionell den **Genitiv**. Bei *anstatt* gibt es eine Ausnahme, wenn es als Konjunktion benutzt wird.